# We should have verbed somebody <when/while> we had the chance

Tags: adverbs

This pattern recurs in many literary works. When I was watching an animated movie the character said just the pattern below. I cannot tell for sure what he said but it was probably *while*. I thought I'd ask about which word is more common, *while or when*.

We should have **verbed** somebody (**when/while**) we had the chance

Examples:

1. We should have  locked him up (when/**while**) we had the chance
2. We should have killed you when we had the chance

**Edit:**
After a repeated listening it turns out that the word was **when**!
Anyway, I don't trust my ear yet. I still need your input.

Now I could think of another reason why it should be *when* and not *while*. While is mostly used, as I see it, in present, pressing situations. And when is just for an event at a point of time in the past.

Comment: The only difference is that ***when*** often refers to a *specific point in time*, whereas ***while*** always refers to some *span* of time. So if you'd only had a split-second window of opportunity kill someone, but you failed to take advantage of that chance, you'd be rather unlikely to use ***while***. To put it another way, the longer you had a chance, the more likely you are to refer back to it with ***while***.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, I put variations into [Google Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=while+we+had+the+chance%2Cwhile+I+had+the+chance%2Cwhen+I+had+the+chance%2Cwhen+we+had+the+chance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhile%20we%20had%20the%20chance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhile%20I%20had%20the%20chance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhen%20I%20had%20the%20chance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhen%20we%20had%20the%20chance%3B%2Cc0), which shows that there are significantly more hits for "when I/we had the chance" over "while".

Either usage is grammatical, but the difference is the context.

> We should have killed you **when** we had the chance

"When" refers to a *specific point* in time - maybe the bad guys are referring to their last scuffle with their potential victim.

> We should have killed you **while** we had the chance

"While" refers to a *period* of time - maybe the bad guys regret not offing the victim during the time they held him captive. (Then again, an argument could be made for "when" in this scenario as well, since it would be a specific time that he was captive.)

There are a couple related questions on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42905/distinguishing-between-when-and-while) and [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141357/how-to-use-when-vs-while-on-the-following-occasions) discussing other cases, which may be interesting to read through as well.

Answer (score 1):

In general, *while* implies a longer period of time:

> during the time that

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/while

while *when* could suggest a single moment, but can be used for longer periods:

> at or during which time

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/when

Depending on the situation, both words can be appropriate.